# How to read batch output in python script

Tags: python, subprocess

I am writing a script in python that will run a batch file, and after the batch is finished would proceed with more actions.

I wrote the code for executing the batch and wait for it to finish. The problem is that if the batch is failed, the script does not know about it.
The batch prints to the console if it finished successfully or failed.
I need your help in order to understand how can I read the batch prints to the console using the script

This is the relevant code:

```
def runAutoFa(self):
    process = Popen([self._batPath], cwd = path, stdin = PIPE)
    process.stdin.write(self._commit)
    time.sleep(2)
    process.stdin.write(self._product)
    time.sleep(2)
    process.stdin.write(self._setupName)
    time.sleep(2)
    process.stdin.close()
    status = process.wait() # The command waits until the batch is finised
    self._logger.flush()
    return status
```

I need to be able to read the prints while still waiting for the batch to complete before continuing with the script

Thanks!

Comment: `stdout` isn't redirected. That should print directly on the console.

Comment: You can use `communicate()`. Something like - `output, error = node_proc.communicate()` instead of `process.wait()`. The python program would wait till the batch process is done with it's execution and then return the output and return code to the two variables. And add `stdout=PIPE` as an arg to the Popen call.

Comment: Or, is your intention to read the output in real time as it is being outputted by your batch file?

Comment: @Jay, I don`t need to read it in real time. I just want to be able to read the result - even after the batch is finished. When using the communicate(), I will still be able to write to the batch the same way?

Comment: How is this question related to the `batch-file` tag? The problem here is _not_ the Batch code! **`:(`**